# finish an activity gives error

Tags: android

I am a beginner at Android programming and I have a little problem when closing an activity:
When I enter my app I navigate to another Activity called *"camp"*, and I want to close the Activity when I come back to the menu screen, so I wrote this:

```
public void onPause(){
    CampActivity.this.finish();
}
```

but when I press the back button I get an error telling me that the application was closed.

What should I do so it will work?

Comment: the method finish() launches the auPause() method.. your approach is wrong.. try provide some code to be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

because `CampActivity.this.finish();` will again call pause function (see activity life cycle ) so you should not call finish in `onPause()`

Comment: how should i close the the activity then?

Comment: Please let us know why you put the CampActivity.this.finish() in onPause() as I am assuming this onPause is of CampActivity ?

Comment: hello Dheeresh Singh, your assumption is right, the onPause is of CampActivity, i want to close it because it includes data that changes every time that the activity is brought to the front so i want the data to be uo to date.( i use editText to display the data)

Comment: as if you are pressing the phones back key, activity will close by self you no need to call finish of that particular activity ...

Comment: you are right i did a little test and its right. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

simply tapping the back button will close the `Activity`. or you can do it using a `Button`

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });
```